# strange (cycles) render result on 2 equal glass lenses

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, glass

Version 2.79 (official) on Win10

I created a lens using a mesh with hyperbolic math function 
(z = sqrt(x^2+y^2 +1) and boolean modifier using a box to cut of.

I used glass BDSF shader, copied the lens with Ctr-D
and rotated one of the two 180° on x-axis
In render view one of the two looks as expected, the other one is completely black. I can reproduce it with exchanging both (the one with convex side on top is black)

What could be the reason ?
(see pictures 1 and 2 with different view angels)

[image: rendered view 1]
[image: rendered view 2]
[image: view 3]

Comment: probably bad normals -> CTRL-N (recalculate in edit mode)

Comment: Your material also has only one user. Double check to make sure both lenses have the proper material.

Comment: Cntrl-N didn't solve the problem.
And I have the same material for each of the lenses, with exactly the same properties (thus you see only one user)

Comment: I deleted the whole file and startet from scratch, now everything works and I can‘ t reproduce.